# slideToggle only clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu and when I click a link that has a submenu, I want to toggle it. And I did that, however I have more submenus with the same class and when I click one all of them toggles.

I managed to toggle only the clicked element but in this case I need to toggle the children.

Here is the js code I have:

```
$('li.has-submenu a.link').click(function() { 
$('.submenu').slideToggle(500);
});
```

And here is a quick fiddle of the situation:
http://jsfiddle.net/TV5Kk/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TV5Kk/2/)

```
$(this).next('.submenu').slideToggle(500);
```

Since you have multiple elements with class `submenu` use `$(this)` to get the relative element. In your mark up, the next element to the link happens to be one you wanted to toggle.

UPDATE:
Since OP wants to automatically slide up all others.

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/TV5Kk/5/)

```
$('li.has-submenu a.link').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').slideUp(500);
    $(this).next('.submenu').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: is it possible to automatically close all others?